# Assembly Manifest loading error (.NET and C++ dlls)

Tags: .net, dll, unmanaged, loading, manifest

My application (pure DotNET 2.0) is referencing another pure DotNET 2.0 dll which is PInvoking into an unmanaged (C++ 2005) dll. On some computers this works fine, on others there is a consistent error message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 
'C:\Program Files\Rhinoceros 4.0\Plug-ins\Grasshopper\rhcommon_c.dll' or one of its dependencies. 
The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

[Assembly Manifest Error http://en.wiki.mcneel.com/content/upload/images/AssemblyManifestError.png](http://en.wiki.mcneel.com/content/upload/images/AssemblyManifestError.png)

I've been googling this error, but it seems that other people are running into it because they have multiple files which are named the same. This is not the case here. There is only one RhinoCommon.dll and only one rhcommon_c.dll

The computer has the latest Microsoft C Runtimes installed.

Much Obliged,
David

---

Edit:
The error message was wrong. It was in fact another dll which was missing. Very weird that DotNET got so confused about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try open your application in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). it should point out which of the dll's is missing.

Comment: I did, and it found 2 missing delay-load dependencies: ( http://en.wiki.mcneel.com/content/upload/images/DependencyWalkerGR.JPG )

When I run the same test on a computer that works correctly, I get a single (different) missing dependency (IESHIMS.DLL)

Is this information important?

Comment: I don't actually think there are missing dlls. It's a problem with loading existing dlls. The thing that confuses me about this particular error is that it is looking for an Assembly Manifest on a C++ only dll. I was under the impression only DotNET dlls contained assembly manifests.